# Action induced by the action of the normalizer $N$ of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ on $G/H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, group-actions

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Consider the set $G/H$
>   of left cosets modulo $H$. The group G operates on $G/H$ on the left
>   by $(g,xH)\mapsto gxH$. Let $N$ be the normalizer of $H$. The group
>   $N$ operates on $G/H$ on the right by $(xH,n)\mapsto xHn=xnH$. This
>   operation induces on H the trivial operation and hence, on passing to
>   the quotient, $N/H$ operates on $G/H$ on the right.

I am not sure what is meant here by

> ...This operation induces on H the trivial operation...

The operation referred to is
$$N\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{G/H},\ (n\mapsto(xH\mapsto xnH));$$

Is the induced operation $H\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{G/H},\ (h\mapsto(xH\mapsto xhH=xH))$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if $h\in H, nhH=nH$ since $hH=H$ since $H$ is a subgroup and $h\in H$. $hH\subset H$ since $h\in H$ and $H$ a subgroup, let $h\in H, h'=h(h^{-1}h')$ and $h^{-1}h'\in H$.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what the homomorphism associated with this trivial induced action is? Is it $H\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{G/H},\ (h\mapsto(xH\mapsto xhH=xH))$?

Comment: The way it's phrased in the quote makes it seem like the trivial induced operation referred to is an operation of $N$ on $H$, which wouldn't make sense...

Comment: There exists a morphism $f:N\rightarrow Aut(G/H)$ defined by $f(n)(xH)=xnH$ since $H$ is contained in $Kerf$, $f$ factors by $G/H$.

Comment: Is $f(n)$ really an endomorphism of $G/H$? i.e. $f(n)((xH)(yH))=f(n)(xyH)=f(n)(xH)f(n)(yH)$? i.e. $xynH=xnHynH$?

Comment: Never mind---I now understand that you meant that $f(n)$ is a $G$-automorphism. Thanks.